# What do macros like GTK_TEXT_VIEW do?

Tags: c, gtk

What does `GTK_TEXT_VIEW (view)` do in the below context?  Is it a function that returns a GtkTextView structure or is it casting "view" into a GtkTextView structure?

```
/* Change left margin throughout the widget */
gtk_text_view_set_left_margin (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (view), 30);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a macro. It casts `view` into a `GtkTextView *` type, in addition to doing a GObject typecheck to make sure the object really is a `GtkTextView`